# add column with cvs.writer

Tags: python, csv, xls

I have a script which opens a cvs and writes it out again (with a different name) without some columns I don't need.

```
source = outname
    with open(source, "rb") as source:
        rdr = csv.reader(source)
        with open("import2SFDC.csv", "wb") as result:
            wtr = csv.writer(result, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            for r in rdr:
                wtr.writerow((r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6], r[7], r[8], r[9], r[10],
                            r[12], r[13], r[14], r[16], r[17], r[18], r[19], r[20], r[21],
                            r[22], r[23], r[24], r[25], r[26], r[27], r[28], r[29], r[33],
                            r[35], r[36], r[37], r[38], r[39], r[40], r[42], r[43], r[44],
                            r[46], r[47], r[48], r[49], r[50], r[51], r[52], r[53], r[54],
                            r[56], r[57], r[60], r[61], r[63], r[70], r[81], r[82]))
```

This works fine so far.
I now would like to ADD a column with a header of "SFDCID". The value for this column should always (i.e. in all rows) be the value of arg.parse:

```
 parser.add_argument("SFDCID", type=str,
                        help="Salesforce ID of the Account the contact should be matched to")
```

So, I call the script with the SFDCID as an argument and this needs to be written as a column into the resulting csv file.

I'm quite new to python and was able to build the original script only because of the great help here, maybe someone can help me with this extension?

thanks

Andre

Comment: Does your original file (the source file, which you are reading) have a header?

Comment: Hi yes, it has, but I think we don't define it as header we just treat it as a row.

Comment: find the complete python code here: http://pastebin.com/542FcDhB

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the header, append your extra header to it and then write out your new file:

```
# These are the columns we will not write
skip = [11, 15, 30, 31, 32, 34, 41, 45, 55, 58, 59, 62]
skip += range(64, 70)
skip += range(71, 81)

with open('read.csv', 'r') as r, open('write.csv', 'w') as w:
    reader = csv.reader(r)
    writer = csv.writer(w, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)
    header.append('SFDCID') # Add the new column
    writer.writerow(header) # write out the new header
    for row in reader:
        new_row = [v for k,v in enumerate(row) if k not in skip]
        new_row.append('your value for SFDCID column')
        writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot Burhan, that really works well. I now just need to "understand" in detail what it's doing, especially the for loop.

Comment: Too quick. Skipping the columns not of interest seems to not work. all columns are written into the resulting csv.

Comment: Hi Burhan. Have you had a chance to look into my last comment / question? Thanks